# FileWriter works only without GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I wanted to make a log in window that saves usernames and passwords in a file created while the program is running: the main problem is that when I run the java from console the program works (here part of the code):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        String s = " ";
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        s = in.nextLine();
        File newTextFile = new File("data.txt");
        FileWriter data = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
        data.write(s);
        data.close();
        } catch (IOException iox) {
          iox.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
```

But when I run this code it doesn't

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LogIn extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField text;
    private JTextField text1;

    public LogIn() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label = new JLabel("Username");
    add(label);

    text = new JTextField(10);
    add(text);

    label1 = new JLabel("Password");
    add(label1);

    text1 = new JTextField(10);
    add(text1);

    button = new JButton("Log In");
    add(button);

    if(button.isSelected())
        try {
            File newTextFile = new File("data.txt");
            FileWriter data = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
            data.write(text.getText());
            data.write(text1.getText());
            data.close();
            } catch (IOException iox) {
              iox.printStackTrace();
              }
            }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LogIn gui = new LogIn();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(200, 125);
    gui.setTitle("Log In");
    gui.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: “But when I run this code it doesn't [work]” How can you tell?

Comment: The program itself works but it doesn't create the .txt file

Comment: `new File("data.txt")` refers to a file in whatever the current directory happens to be when you run the program.  Try using an absolute path, like `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "data.text")`.

Comment: I knew it, and I also just tried your code but it's still not working, all I get is the GUI and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that :

```
if(button.isSelected())
```

add an `ActionListener` to the `JButton`.

`isSelected()` method returns the state of the button. `True` if the toggle button is selected, `false` if it's not.

It is not what you need since you want only to associate a button click to an action and you don't use a toggle button.

Try rather this code :

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      try {
          File newTextFile = new File("data.txt");
          FileWriter data = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
          data.write(text.getText());
          data.write(text1.getText());
          data.close();
        } 
          catch (IOException iox) {
             iox.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

    }
});
```